# Is it possible to write a SQL Query to extract send data that includes Tags and/or Campaign names

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

We are trying to do some reporting based on emails with specific tags or associated to specific campaigns over the past 12 months. I have tired to use the Analytics builder > Reports to get the data however there doesn't seam to be a option to add a tag or campaign column.

We need Email Name, Email Subject, Send Year, Send Month, Sends and either campaign name or tag. I assume tag would be harder as you could have multiple unless you restrict to tag = "specific name".

So as the data cant be gained via the Reports dashboard, i wondered if anyone has done it via a SQL query or is this data not obtainable?

Thanks 
Andy

Comment: Unfortunately, campaign/tags information is not available via Query. You can try Tracking extract. It does have a Campaign ID attribute that might be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom report to achieve this. You need to select 'Discover' from report category and search for 'Blank Template for Email Sending Performance'.

Here you can drag and drop the campaign name, email name, send month and send year in 'Rows'.

[image]

You can schedule this report to be delivered to your email ID or FTP location or can be downloaded too as per your requirement.

Please note that you might not find this type of report in your marketing cloud instance. In that case, you can raise a support ticket and they can get it enabled for you.

Comment: Where do you find this "view" i haven't seen this inside the marketing cloud. Is this inside the marketing cloud?

Comment: Yes this is in Marketing Cloud. You can find it in Analytics Builder->Reports. Under Report categories in the Overview page, you will find 'Discover' option. Under that you can opt for 'Blank Template for Email Sending Performance' report.

Comment: FYI for others: You need to setup discovers which takes up to 24h and after that this options (might) become usable.

Comment: Thanks for that, i dont know how i missed it. Was using reports just kept missing the Campaign name field

Answer (score 1):

Discover has been retired. Use Intelligence reports to track through campaign.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_january_2021_discover_reports_retires.htm&type=5