# Tag emails and use the tags is SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, tag

Is there any way to tag/attribute a tag to an email (to categorize them for example) and use it in the SQL queries to get tracking information by email types (transactional, commercial, welcome pack, etc) ?

Thanks

Ludivine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question discusses querying tags and campaigns ([Is it possible to write a SQL Query to extract send data that includes Tags and/or Campaign names](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249410/is-it-possible-to-write-a-sql-query-to-extract-send-data-that-includes-tags-and)) - apparently not possible.

However, if you want to break down tracking information by transactional, commercial, etc, you could consider using specific Send Classifications for the email sends. You are probably already using "Default Commercial" and "Default Transactional" for their respective sends. You can create additional ones (eg: we have a send classification for "Reengagement").

The Send Classification value is then available on the _Job view, making it very easy to use in SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a shame we can't use "tags" or "campaigns" on emails in the SQL. I also thought about using the Send classifications as a workaround.